# LINQ - Getting a subset based on type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Animal>` which contains objects of type `Cat`, `Dog` and `Pig` (For simplicity)

I wish to select all the Dogs into a new `List<Dog>` from my `List<Animal>`.

How is that done in LINQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var dogs = animals.OfType<Dog>().ToList();
```

(Note that the `ToList()` is only required to make a `List<Dog>`.  If you just need `IEnumerable<Dog>`, you can leave it off.)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
var animals = new List<Animals> { new Dog(), new Cat(), new Pig(), }; //etc.
var dogs = 
  animals
  .OfType<Dog>()
  .ToList();
```